# Running Safari with debug version of Webkit

Tags: macos, webkit

I compiled a debug version of webkit by running the following command.

> Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --debug

After a successful build, I tried to run safari with the compiled debug version of Webkit by running the following command.

```
sudo Tools/Scripts/run-safari --debug
```

However I am getting the following errors:

> Starting SafariForWebKitDevelopment with DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH set to
>   point to built WebKit in
>   /Users/syst3m/Desktop/Research/webkit/WebKit/WebKitBuild/Debug.
>   _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL. 2019-01-30
>   10:34:16.527 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[81259:1239156]
>   +[NSXPCSharedListener endpointForReply:withListenerName:]: an error occurred while attempting to obtain endpoint for listener
>   'SandboxBroker': Connection invalid

Are there any more setup that needs to be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here, but regardless of debug/release build. Moreover, entering address in the navigation bar and hitting enter doesn't work, so doesn't devtools "Inspect", though navigating through clicks on the "most frequent" works. Minibrowser also works, but Safari is broken.

Comment: This looks like a WebKit bug, tracked here <https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194808>

Answer (score 2):

You need to give Terminal "Full Disk Access". (or iTerm or whatever you are issuing the command from)

"System Preferences" -> "Security & Privacy" -> "Full Disk Access" -> "+"

http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/