# How to run WebKit via the bisect-builds script?

Tags: macos, webkit

WebKit has a script that is supposed to help bisect regressions as mentioned in [this webkit blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/7978/introducing-webkit-build-archives/)

I'm trying it out with

```
./bisect-builds -p mac-mojave -a x86_64 -c release -s 230000 -e 242118
```

and it downloads a release and runs the release but I can not navigate to any webpages regardless of which release it downloads. I can click a bookmark but typing a URL never works. I can not edit bookmarks (picking edit bookmarks does nothing)

When running I see the errors below in the terminal. That makes me wonder if I need to set some environment variables or something to tell webkit to not use `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari` and similar library folders but instead use some temp folder for all it's files since otherwise it would seem like they'd conflict with the system version of Safari.

[This page on running webkit mentions nothing](https://webkit.org/running-webkit/)

I don't know those errors are the cause of not being able to navigate to pages but whatever the reason, so far it's been impossible to bisect if I can't load a test webpage.

How I can run the webkit bisect-builds script in a way that actually lets me test each webkit revision it launches?

> Starting SafariForWebKitDevelopment with DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH set to point to built WebKit in /var/folders/7h/wyw4jhd933z5jmqzsdx6r0sr0000gn/T/tmp6D8gwS/Release.
>   2019-02-27 11:58:59.835 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[43176:20392508] NetworkStorageDB:_openDBReadConnections: failed to open read connection to DB @ /Users/gregg/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db.  Error=14. Cause=unable to open database file
>   2019-02-27 11:58:59.835 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[43176:20392508] CacheRead: unable to open cache files in /Users/gregg/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari
>   2019-02-27 11:58:59.836 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[43176:20392508] Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/Users/gregg/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari. Errno:1
>   2019-02-27 11:58:59.836 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[43176:20392508] NetworkStorageDB:_openDBReadConnections: failed to open read connection to DB @ /Users/gregg/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db.  Error=14. Cause=unable to open database file
>   2019-02-27 11:58:59.836 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[43176:20392508] CacheRead: unable to open cache files in /Users/gregg/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari
>   2019-02-27 11:58:59.836 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[43176:20392508] Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/Users/gregg/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari. Errno:1
>   Failed to open AutoFill corrections SQLite store at AutoFillCorrections.db. Error: Error Domain=com.apple.Safari.SQLite Code=14 "unable to open database file"
>   _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
>   Failed to open cahce settings store at file:///Users/gregg/Library/Safari/Touch%20Icons%20Cache/TouchIconCacheSettings.db: Error Domain=com.apple.Safari.SQLite Code=14 "unable to open database file"
>   2019-02-27 11:59:00.100 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[43176:20392508] NetworkStorageDB:_openDBReadConnections: failed to open read connection to DB @ /Users/gregg/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db.  Error=14. Cause=unable to open database file
>   2019-02-27 11:59:00.100 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[43176:20392508] CacheRead: unable to open cache files in /Users/gregg/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari
>   2019-02-27 11:59:00.100 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[43176:20392508] Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/Users/gregg/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari. Errno:1
>   Failed to open AutoFill corrections SQLite store at CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. Error: Error Domain=com.apple.Safari.SQLite Code=14 "unable to open database file"
>   Failed to open AutoFill corrections SQLite store at AutoFillCorrections.db. Error: Error Domain=com.apple.Safari.SQLite Code=14 "unable to open database file"
>   Failed to open AutoFill corrections SQLite store at CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. Error: Error Domain=com.apple.Safari.SQLite Code=14 "unable to open database file"
>   2019-02-27 11:59:00.417 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[43176:20392529] +[NSXPCSharedListener endpointForReply:withListenerName:]: an error occurred while attempting to obtain endpoint for listener 'SandboxBroker': Connection invalid
>   Failed to open AutoFill corrections SQLite store at AutoFillCorrections.db. Error: Error Domain=com.apple.Safari.SQLite Code=14 "unable to open database file"
>   Failed to open AutoFill corrections SQLite store at CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. Error: Error Domain=com.apple.Safari.SQLite Code=14 "unable to open database file"
>   2019-02-27 11:59:00.560 SafariForWebKitDevelopment[43176:20392510] AOSKit ERROR: XPC CLIENT: Unauthorized client error received
>   Failed to open AutoFill corrections SQLite store at AutoFillCorrections.db. Error: Error Domain=com.apple.Safari.SQLite Code=14 "unable to open database file"
>   Failed to open AutoFill corrections SQLite store at CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. Error: Error Domain=com.apple.Safari.SQLite Code=14 "unable to open database file"
>   _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
>   _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
>   Failed to open cahce settings store at file:///Users/gregg/Library/Safari/Touch%20Icons%20Cache/TouchIconCacheSettings.db: Error Domain=com.apple.Safari.SQLite Code=14 "unable to open database file"
>   _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establis...

Comment: This seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436381/running-safari-with-debug-version-of-webkit?rq=1

Comment: Answered over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436381/running-safari-with-debug-version-of-webkit Enable "Full Disk Access"